# why does wikipedia api give me error on beautifulsoup4 or something

Tags: python

i am running this code from geeksforgeeks

```
    # importing the module
import wikipedia

# finding result for the search
# sentences = 2 refers to numbers of line
result = wikipedia.summary("India", sentences = 2)

# printing the result
print(result)
```

but it always gives me this error

C:\Users*censored*\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py:389: GuessedAtParserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 389 of the file C:\Users*censored*\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="html.parser"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

lis = BeautifulSoup(html).find_all('li' "html.parser")

any help will be appreciated

Comment: It's not an error. As the message tells you, it's a warning. It also tells you how to get rid of it.

Comment: As mentioned by @enzo it's a warning and a known issue. Look at https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/issues?q=warning

Comment: Actually, it sort of "worked` for me. I get `wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError: "indian" may refer to:` in addition to the warning

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's not an error but a warning (in case it works).
The parser is a way to construct the "text"or tree from a webpage - different parsers (might) give different results, if e.g the webpage have some HTML-errors, see examples
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers.

If you don't specify which parser to use, beautifulsoup chooses one for you (that's the warning you see).

Comment: the OP problem is they use third-party package where the actual problem is.

Comment: It's correct - I don't know if you can specify the parser in the Wikipedia package. But OP asked what the warning is and where it comes from

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with Wikipedia. Try passing a local HTML document and you will get the same warning. Relevant information can be found in the warning message and the very beginning of the document of Beautifulsoup.